# Updated rows in DataGridView not reflecting in UI C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a WinForms application & it has DataGridView.

It has a form TaskPane. If I add any new row in the constructor it adds while at any other place it doesn't.

```
  public TaskPane(List<Tuple<string, string>> entities =null)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        tabTextForReview.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        dgEntitiesForReview.Rows.Add("StaticKey", "StaticContent");

        if (entities!= null)
        {
            foreach (var entity in entities)
            {
                dgEntitiesForReview.Rows.Add(entity.Item1, entity.Item2);
                // tried with ->dgEntitiesForReview.Rows.Add("DynamicKey", "DynamicContent");
            }
            dgEntitiesForReview.ClearSelection();
            dgEntitiesForReview.Refresh();

        }
 }
```

When the form is loaded for at first, the StaticKey row is added & reflects in UI. While when updating the rows at any other instance (or second time or from any method) the rows are not reflected in UI.

Second Instance Call(on button click)

```
public void btnSubmitClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   TaskPane tp = new TaskPane(new List<Tuple<string,string>>(){
      new Tuple<string,string>("DyanmicKey", "DynamicContent");
  });
}
```

While if I check in QuickWatch window I can see the rows count is updated.

*Please note the DataGridView has "Adding/Editing/Deleting Enabled"*

How to reflect this in UI?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you update rows?

Comment: It would be difficult to reproduce with the information provided. Can you show how you're trying to add these values *at any other instance*? If you place a button in the Form and in its Click event, right after the Form is loaded, you add a list of values to the DGV, does the problem reproduce? Are you setting a DataSource at some point?

Comment: @Jimi On button click, Please check the updated post

Comment: @Jimi This is an alternate that I was testing, the same addRows is another method say AddRowsToGrid() but the same issue so I tried putting in the constrcutor

Comment: You know that with `TaskPane tp = new TaskPane(...)` you're creating a new instance of TaskPane, distinct from the TaskPain you have already initialized and shown, right? (the constructor is not a method you can call as you please) Where did you subscribe to `btnSubmitClick`? In another Form, maybe? Place a Button in the TaskPane Form and simply add a few Rows to the DGV from there, as you did in the constructor: `dgEntitiesForReview.Rows.Add(...)`.

Comment: @Jimi updated accordingly & checked. Still the same issue

Comment: Then you're still making the same mistake (or a new one). Where is the code you tried? You didn't update your question. -- Are you still doing ~this: `var t = new TaskPane(...)`? If so, then don't.

Comment: If you're trying to update the DGV in TaskPane from another Form/Class, then make a public method in TaskPane that accepts a `List<Tuple<string, string>>` as argument. Then call this public method, using the **current instance** of TaskPane (you can pass the instance to other classes).

Comment: @Jimi Could you please suggest? Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60487316/how-to-update-the-content-of-datagridview-present-in-another-form-after-the-data