# How to update the content of DataGridView present in another form after the data is bound

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, add-in

I have WordAddin & it has n forms. Of Which below are 2 forms

1. TaskPane
2. RibbonPane

RibbonPane has button on the click of which I need to add rows in DataGridView docked inside a TabPane contained in TaskPane.

But the data in the datagrid view(or textbox) is set to the value that is set in the TaskPane constructor. While my requirement is on ButtonClick contained in RibbonPane I need to update the content of the DataGridView(i.e., Add Rows)

```
 //Ribbon.cs
 public void btnSubmitClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   var obj = new TaskPane();
   obj.AddRowsToDGV(new List<Tuple<string, string>>()
   {
        new Tuple<string,string>("Google","CEO");
   });
 };


 //TaskPane.cs
  public TaskPane()
  { 
   //below reflects in UI
   dgEntitiesForReview.Rows.Add("Static","ForTesting"); 
  }

  public AddRowsToDGV(List<Tuple<string, string>> entities =null)
  { 
       //dgEntitiesForReview - DataGridView docked inside TabPage/TabControl
        if (entities!= null)
        {
            foreach (var entity in entities)
            {
                dgvEntities.Rows.Add(entity.Item1, entity.Item2);
            }
            dgEntitiesForReview.ClearSelection();
            dgEntitiesForReview.Refresh();
        }
 }
```

If I add a watch of quickwatch dgEntitiesForReview.Rows.Count it is updated but the same is not reflecting in UI?

***Please note I checked with putting a simple textbox in place of DataGridView but the same issue.Text getting updated while debugging but not reflecting in UI***

Thanks!

Comment: You're (still) making [the same mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60449603/7444103):  in `btnSubmitClick()` of the `Ribbon` class you have `var obj = new TaskPane();` This is **a new** TaskPane, not the one currently loaded and shown. You cannot use this instance, it's **completely unrelated** to the existing one. You need to pass the current instance of TaskPane to your Ribbon class and use **this existing instance** to update your **current TaskPane Form**. + If the DGV is bound to a DataSource, you need to add the data to the DataSource, not the Control. Use a BindingSource.

Comment: @Jimi But how ?

Comment: What controls the creation of these Forms? Can you store the reference of a Form when it's created? Can you use [Application.OpenForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms)? Which one, Ribbons or TaskPane, is created first? What relations do these Forms have? The method you choose depends on the structure of your application.

Answer (score 0):

In your foreach loop in AddRowsToDGV method, are you using the correct gridview? You are adding rows to **dgvEntities** and checking for row count on **dgEntitiesForReview**